# How did Loki create a nexus event in Endgame if Endgame was "supposed to happen"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, loki-2021

From my understanding, a nexus event is when someone does something that goes against the Sacred Timeline, specifically things that have cascading effects.

The Avengers' actions in *Endgame* didn't create a nexus event because they were "supposed to happen" (Renslayer, Ep01). Loki taking the Tesseract did create one so he was captured by the TVA.

However some of the events of *Endgame* only happened **because** he took the Tesseract, i.e. Stark and Rogers going to 1970 to get the Tesseract.

If the 1970 mission was supposed to happen, then surely Loki making it happen by taking the Tesseract should also have supposed to happen. So how did it make a nexus event?

Comment: I'll add a caution that the last episode is yet to come out, and we don't know who/what is truly behind the TVA. For example, they may have made up nexus events entirely to drive the timeline towards some goal. The true answer may not be available until the finale is released.

Comment: https://www.slashfilm.com/avengers-endgame-final-scene-explained/  everyone should read this again.  I'd speculate that TVA wants the two major Endgame timelines to exist - but do not want Loki running around in the second one.  Most variants appear to be spontaneous splits anyway and do not require Endgame level time travel events.  Scientifically (in a scifi MCU sense) if any mere subatomic particle took a trip back in time that would split the universe and provide a degree of freedom for someone to make a choice the TVA didn't approve of.

Comment: Saw this in the top-10 while browsing somewhere else. Spoiler much?

Comment: @AnoE If you feel the title is too spoilery you can always suggest an edit to improve it, though some balance needs to be struck between a useful title and one that's too spoilery.

Comment: Simply, it was meant to be the Avengers who take the Space Stone, not Loki.

Comment: Also, when the Avengers _actually_ took the Space Stone, it was _before_ 2012, so technically had already happened and didn't need to happen again in 2012...

Comment: Also, wibbly-wobbly timey-wimey stuff.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Firstly, what we see in *Avengers: Endgame* around that point is already in a nexus event. We're watching the branched timeline as we see Loki take the Tesseract and escape. This means that the Sacred Timeline is slightly different. This could be something as small as Loki just never actually picks up the Tesseract to escape but the plan is shot and they can't get it themselves now. Or it could be something completely different altogether. I don't think there's any information on what should have actually happened here though.

Note though that as per the rules set up in *Avengers: Endgame* the branched timeline that Infinity Stones are taken from can be erased by simply putting the Stones back so they never really left.

> **The Ancient One:** The Infinity Stones create what you experience as the flow of time. Remove one of the stones, and that flow splits. Now this may benefit your reality. But my new one, not so much. In this new branched reality, without our chief weapon against the forces of darkness, our world will be overrun. Millions will suffer. So, tell me, doctor, can your science prevent all that?
>
> **Banner:** No. But we can erase it. Because once we're done with the stones, we can return each one into its own timeline at the moment it was taken. So, chronologically... In that reality.... it never left.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Whilst the Tesseract was not taken out of this timeline the Time Stone and the Mind Stone (inside the Scepter) were taken and then placed back. This means that any branched reality here was erased as the Stone was returned. As the timeline continued as it should do this means no nexus event is created around this moment.

It is worth noting though that head writer for Loki has the following to say:

> Marvel already made its case for how time travel works in *Avengers: Endgame*, but that, Waldron points out, “is the way the Avengers understand it.” With a TV show it’s a little different. “I was always very acutely aware of the fact that there’s a week between each of our episodes and these fans are going to do exactly what I would do, which is pick this apart. We wanted to create a time-travel logic that was so airtight it could sustain over six hours. There’s some time-travel sci-fi concepts here that I’m eager for my *Rick and Morty* colleagues to see.”
>
> <sub>[Vanity Fair, How the Man Behind *Loki* Is Shaping Marvel’s Phase 4 and Beyond](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2021/06/loki-michael-waldron-doctor-strange-star-wars-rick-and-morty)</sub>

This just means that what we understand from *Avengers: Endgame* isn't entirely true and that makes sense given Markus and McFeely's comments in the past about Steve staying in the same timeline, paraphrasing from memory: *"there are time travel loopholes for that"*.

Comment: Your ancient one and Banner quote says the opposite of what you claim it does.  According to Endgame ANY time travel causes a branch which is why there are no paradoxes.

Comment: @lucasbachmann How does it say the opposite? And in Endgame it's only stated that removing an Infinity Stone causes a branch. Time travel means you simply don't go into your own past but rather your future.

Comment: There are numerous quotes in endgame that discuss time travel. (And posts on this topic specifically about it) None of them say ONLY removing stones causes a branch.  They ALL say doing anything in the past is paradox free because as you just stated "it's not your past".  Removing the time stone will certainly be noticeable if not returned but it isn't what branched the timeline.  The time travel merely to have the conversation did.

Comment: @lucasbachmann I think we'll have to agree to disagree on this one. In the Ancient One's explanation time only branches once an Infinity Stone is removed and she's aware he's from the future so she should know whether time would branch on time travel or not.

Comment: Her timeline graph is a misery index and Banner is saying the two timelines will proceed in the same direction because he doesn't intend for her universe to not have stones because he intends to return them at the same time they are borrowed.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - Her timeline graph is a measure of the lack of economic and social well-being of the inhabitants of a country?

Comment: @Adamant Dormammu invading is bad for the economy.   Women and minorities hit hardest by the destruction of Earth.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - Uh, I mean, Dormammu also wanted to suck the planet into a hell dimension, but I guess you could could focus on the economy if you like.

Comment: "simply putting the Stones back so they never really left" I never really understood this... with how complicated getting the stones was... how is putting them back "simple"?

Comment: @WernerCD It was complicated because the old scientist was dead and they didn't have a lot of time-travel fuel. Once resurrected, they can go whenever they want easily.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Feel free to watch the scene again. When Banner places the stone back, the branching timeline disappears. The whole point is that only big changes create a new timeline and that if they put back the stone a few moments after taking it, the universe perceive it as if nothing really happened.

Comment: It's not that *only* removing an infinity stone can cause a timeline branch, but rather removing a stone is an act that *definitely will* cause a branch. Using time travel to close the loop, returning the stone only moments after taking it, will fix the problem -- not because branching is impossible, but because they've been careful not to do anything that alters the past and have ensured that the stones are right where they were supposed to be in the future.

Comment: @WernerCD On top of that, how *can* they all be returned?  I'm thinking of the Soul Stone here - do you just drop it off the cliff?  Or can you do an exchange?  "Um, yeah, Mr. Red Skull, sir (hey, long time, no see, how's it been?), well, anyhow, when we picked this up, we, well, sort of, you know, left a *deposit*?  I was just wondering if there was any chance we could, you know, get her back?  No?  Are you sure?  Alright, couldn't hurt to ask, you know how it is..."

Comment: @Echox time travel is one part of "putting the stones back". They have Red Juice now. GREAT! but.. Going back to, say, New York at the moment the old stone gets got... or how are you going to return the stone to the guy that demands a sacrifice? You give it to him before? So he has 2? After?  You just going to walk up to him after he's been released? How do you trap him again? The amount of handwaving on those parts is... hard to swallow in a world with green monsters... (edit: Darrel says much of the same)

Answer (score 27):

### Unclear at this time

It is not certain that anything about the "Sacred Timeline" is actually truthful. Revelations in later episodes of *Loki* suggest that there may be ulterior motives for the nudges in the timeline, from ensuring a "correct" future to harvesting variants for the agency's own use. In fact, a common fan theory about Loki's Variants is that they are being pruned because the TVA is trying to avoid a situation where he achieves personal growth, and ceases to be a chronic backstabber and be a thorn in the side of the Avengers.

Ultimately, I suspect the answer may not be provided until later episodes of the show.

Comment: I agree with this so have upvoted, however, I personally believe that what we've heard about the Sacred Timeline is true... the TVA are forcing one timeline so the answer here may still be the same. It's just the motives for _why_ they are doing so and who is in control that aren't exactly truthful.

Comment: It would appear that the motivations of the TVA were pretty truthful.

Comment: And the ending reminds me of the ending of the first season of Jackie Chan animated series.

Answer (score 11):

The Avengers put the stones back where they came from. That ensured the timeline wouldn't branch regardless of when they were taken. They erased the branches themselves so the TVA didn't have to:

> We can erase it. Once we’re done with the stones, we can return each one to its own timeline the moment it was taken so, chronologically, in that reality, it never left.
>
> <sup>-- Bruce Banner, *Avengers: Endgame (2019)*</sup>

However, Loki stealing a stone does create a nexus event, because he had no intention of putting it back. The branch would continue without TVA intervention.

Comment: Banner is NOT saying the timeline will be erased rather the risk to a universe missing its stones because they effectively won't be gone if they are put back.  Further Loki stealing a stone doesn't remove it from its universe but it apparently is a deviation from its fate as defined by TVA.

Comment: @lucasbachmann "it" is "this new branched reality". Banner is 100% saying that the branched timeline will be erased. Removing the stone 100% creates a new one. It couldn't be more clearly stated.

Comment: No - the "it" is "Millions will suffer. So, tell me, doctor, can your science prevent all that?"

Comment: @lucasbachmann no, that's not how English conversation works. Even if it did, that changes nothing. The branched reality in which millions will suffer will be erased.

Comment: The situation leading to suffering will not happen but there will still be 2 universes. And yes it is how English works.

Comment: @lucasbachmann you are simply wrong I'm afraid

Comment: Note your quote of Banner "own timeline"  and "in that reality, "  which is English for 2 universes - albeit ones with minimal differences.  Even TVA educational videos depict the sacred timeline as a rope of threads in the same direction rather than an individual thread.

Comment: @OrangeDog Actually, English doesn't have rules like that. It has guidelines. While the subject is often clear, there are situations in which it is not. This is one of those. It would take clarification from the person making the statement to figure it out. Also, we don't have a good way of talking about novel things like alternate realities because English developed for centuries before that concept even arose.

Comment: @OrangeDog In this specific instance, "we can erase it" is a substitution/modification for "can your science prevent all that" - which clearly was in regards to the broader outcome of the removal of the stone(s), the pain and suffering, not the existence of the alternate reality. Of course he's wrong... you'd just end up with yet another branch where the stone was returned. Screwing with time is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

An entirely plausible explanation is that the Variant Loki was indeed meant to steal the Teseract and create a "planned" nexus event.

A nexus event isn't something happening differently to what was "written" in the Sacred Timeline. It's something that could, if left unchecked, lead to an entirely new timeline.

These two definitions usually go hand-in-hand: if something goes differently from what was written in the Sacred Timeline, it could lead to a new timeline. That's a nexus event.

However, the two definitions can also diverge in that the Sacred Timeline might include things which are at risk of becoming nexus events. So sure, Variant Loki was "meant" to steal the Teseract so that *Endgame* could happen as "written" in the Sacred Timeline. He was also "meant" to be subsequently pruned so that he otherwise had no impact on the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Sacred Timeline isn't perfect. We know that because Sylvie wasn't taken at birth and lived a few years of life before the TVA showed up.

My guess then is that because the Avengers were able to get the Infinity Stones all the same and didn't die or anything, they weren't reset at all. So even though what Loki did wasn't supposed to happen, it ended up working out with little to no cascading effect.